# byte[] responseBody is null if the search_text is correct

Tags: php, android, mysql

Why is it that when my query is wrong I get a response of `[{"result":"NO RECORD FOUND"}]` but when my query is correct I have no response?

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("user_id", UserEducator.getID(context));
params.put("user_token", UserEducator.getToken(context));
params.put("search_text", search_text.trim());
Debugger.logD("user_token " + UserEducator.getToken(context));
Debugger.logD("user_id " + UserEducator.getID(context));
Debugger.logD("search_text " + search_text);
HttpProvider.post(context, "controller_global/SearchUsers.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        String str = new String(responseBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Debugger.logD("str " + str);
        if (str.contains("NO RECORD FOUND"))
            emptyIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else{
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);
                Debugger.logD("jsonArray " + jsonArray);
                for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Debugger.logD("e " + e);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        OkayClosePopup.showDialog(context, "No internet connect. Please try again.", "Close");
    }
});
```

My logcat:

```
wrong = search_text Wrong,
correct = search_text Naruto

2020-06-12 10:22:02.572 9242-9242/com.theyestech.yes_mobile D/YES: user_token 954497023a6ed1b60f8fda2f87a2fc3a
2020-06-12 10:22:02.572 9242-9242/com.theyestech.yes_mobile D/YES: user_id 152
2020-06-12 10:22:02.573 9242-9242/com.theyestech.yes_mobile D/YES: search_text Wrong
2020-06-12 10:22:03.320 9242-9242/com.theyestech.yes_mobile D/YES: str [{"result":"NO RECORD FOUND"}]
2020-06-12 10:22:11.156 9242-9242/com.theyestech.yes_mobile D/YES: user_token 954497023a6ed1b60f8fda2f87a2fc3a
2020-06-12 10:22:11.156 9242-9242/com.theyestech.yes_mobile D/YES: user_id 152
2020-06-12 10:22:11.156 9242-9242/com.theyestech.yes_mobile D/YES: search_text Naruto
2020-06-12 10:22:11.269 9242-9242/com.theyestech.yes_mobile D/YES: str 
2020-06-12 10:22:11.270 9242-9242/com.theyestech.yes_mobile D/YES: e org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

PHP code 
SearchUsers.php

```
 $database = new Database();
 $db = $database->connect();

 $post = new Post($db);

 $post->user_token = isset($_POST["user_token"]) ? $_POST["user_token"] : die();
 $post->user_id = isset($_POST["user_id"]) ? $_POST["user_id"] : die();
 $post->search_text = isset($_POST["search_text"]) ? $_POST["search_text"] : die();

 $rs = $post->SearchUser();
 $post_arr = array();

 if($post->messageresult == "success"){
  if($rs->rowCount() > 0){

    while($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);
        if($user_image == null || $user_image == ""){$user_image = 'default_image.png';}
        $connected = $post->DetectConnection($user_id);
        $post_item = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,'user_token' => $user_token,'user_code' => $user_code,
            'user_email_address' => $user_email_address,'user_password' => $user_password,'user_firstname' => $user_firstname,

                'user_lastname' => $user_lastname,'user_middlename' => $user_middlename,'user_suffixes' => $user_suffixes,
                'user_gender' => $user_gender,'user_contact_number' => $user_contact_number,
                'user_image' => $user_image,'user_educational_attainment' => $user_educational_attainment,'user_subj_major' => $user_subj_major,
                'user_current_school' => $user_current_school,'user_position' => $user_position,
                'user_facebook' => $user_facebook,'user_instagram' => $user_instagram,'user_twitter' => $user_twitter,
                'user_gmail' => $user_gmail,'user_motto' => $user_motto,'user_activation' => $user_activation,
                'user_role' => $user_role,'validated' => $validated,
                'result' => 'success_educator','connection' => $connected,
            );
            array_push($post_arr, $post_item);
        }
    }
}else{
    $post_item = array(
    'result' => "NO RECORD FOUND",
);
array_push($post_arr, $post_item);
}
echo json_encode($post_arr);
```

I have tested it in the browser and everything's fine.

```
function search_users(formData){
    $('#search_user_list').html('');
    formData.append('user_id', user_id);
    formData.append('user_token', user_token);
    $.ajax({
      url: "controllerClass/controller_global/SearchUsers.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: (formData),
      success: function (data) {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          $('#search_subject_list').html('');
          if(data[0].result == "NO RECORD FOUND"){
            $('#search_user_list').append('<section class="section-search-subject"><div class="educator-subject-image"><h1 style="text-align:center;">NO RECORD FOUND</h1></center></section>');
          }else{
            $.each(data, function (data, data) {
              DisplaySearchUsers(data)
            });
          }
      },
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
      });
}
```

Comment: Something goes wrong when you create the `jsonArray`. What does `str` look like at that moment. Add a debug log call right before the line `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);`

Comment: i have a value on responseBody, goes like this responseBody [B@e40d281, however, when converting to string, it becomes empty string

Comment: just going thorugh the code of `SearhUser.php` and there is no else condition for  `if($rs->rowCount() > 0)`. can you try returning some error message or put some data like `NO RECORD FOUND` in the `$post_item` array if query is successfully run with 0 records.

Comment: i'm sorry but stil same result, i can't get pass through messageresult == "success" because str is null when i have a successful query

Comment: Thank you for your support sirs, i just found out the cause of this. 
everytime i run my app in android studio, i get disconnected from the server. so,
i need to login again and again. i don't know how but it works. got the result 
that i wanted.